# jQuery/Javascript: Click event on a checkbox and the 'checked' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

The code:

```
$('input.media-checkbox').live('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);

    if (that.attr('checked') == 'checked'){

        var m = that.attr('media');
        var mid = 'verify_' + m;
        that.parents('div.state-container').find('ul.' + mid).remove();
        that.attr('checked', false);
    } else {

        var url = AJAX_URL;

        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data){

                that.parents('li').siblings('li.verification').children('div.media-verification').append(data).fadeIn(500);
                that.attr('checked', 'checked');
           }
        }); 
    }

    return false;
});
```

I am ajaxing in a form, then firing the click event on relevant checkboxes to ajax in another partial if necessary.  The form is inserted nicely, and the click events are fired, checking the boxes that need to be checked and firing the second ajax, since the `checked` attribute of the checkbox was initially `false`.

What's curdling my cheese is if I UNCHECK one of those boxes.  Despite `e.preventDefault()`, the `checked` attribute is set to `false` BEFORE the test, so the `if` statement always executes the `else` statement.  I've also tried this with `$.is(':checked')`, so I'm completely baffled.

It appears that unchecked -> checked state reads the original state, but checked -> unchecked doesn't.  Any help?

Comment: did you try `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault`? Also, did you use `function(e) { e = e || event; ... }` ?

Comment: `return false`, yes - it's at the end of the code.  Should it be inside the `if` closure?  I'm not familiar with the second bit of code ... what's it for?

Comment: the second bit is checking if `e` is non-null, if not it assigns to the global `event` variable.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin - `e = e || event` is unnecessary in jQuery, it normalizes the event object for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

B.E.,  I know it has been a year but I think I found the solution,

The issue here is that the click event actually get's called and runs BEFORE the "checked" property is added to the checkbox input. So the function runs, looks to see if the input has the "checked" attribute, and runs the else condition. THEN the element is given the "checked" property.

I just ran into this as well, and my solution was to bind the function to the change function rather than the click function, as change only fires AFTER the checked property has been updated on the input.

Hopefully this help you, and if not, anyone else who happens to stumble upon this post while experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Tested against the original project (still in production, with a workaround) - and it works.  Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Well, right. You have set the `live` event, so I *think* your script might also be responding to setting it as checked, but I can't totally tell what you're trying for here without seeing markup, but here's my rewrite.

```
$('input.media-checkbox').live('click', function(e){

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var m = $(this).attr('media');
        var mid = 'verify_' + m;
        $(this).parents('div.state-container')
            .find('ul.' + mid)
            .remove();
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        var url = AJAX_URL;
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $(that).parents('li')
                    .siblings('li.verification')
                    .children('div.media-verification')
                    .append(data)
                    .fadeIn(500);
                $(that).attr('checked', true);
            }
        }); 
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: I need the `.live` event handler, since the form in question isn't in the document when it's loaded - it's ajax'd in afterwards.  Setting a straight `.bind` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault()` and also remove `return false`. Returning `false` in jQuery is equivalent to `e.stopPropagation()` + `e.preventDefault()`. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the checkbox from being `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a due to asynchronous requests. The execution goes past `$.ajax`, before it's success callback fires. When you click the checkbox again, it's state has not yet been updated by the previous request's callback. What you can try is to disable the checkbox control prior to firing the ajax call, and enable it again within the success callback:

```
that.attr("disabled", "disabled");
var url = AJAX_URL;   
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){

        that.parents('li').siblings('li.verification').children('div.media-verification').append(data).fadeIn(500);
        that.attr('checked', 'checked');
        that.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

That will ensure that two successive clicks will not lead to unpredictable behaviour. The other way would be to use a synchronous request, i.e. `async: false` but that will block the entire browser for it's duration.

Comment: I like this - but no.  The checkbox being toggled is already in the DOM - this ajax call (for a second request) is made after the test for `:checked`, so the success of the ajax request doesn't affect the state of the checkbox.  Check a checkbox, and jQuery reads in the correct starting state of the checkbox - uncheck it, and it clears the box BEFORE firing the click event handler.  It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to a weird bug in IE. Check/set attribute **defaultChecked** along with **checked**. Try this in your if condition,

```
if (that.attr('checked')=='checked' || that.attr("defaultChecked")=='checked'){     
      var m = that.attr('media');  
      var mid = 'verify_' + m;
      that.parents('div.state-container').find('ul.' + mid).remove();
      that.attr('checked', false);
      that.attr('defaultChecked', false); 
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only a partial answer, but in your test, `$(this).attr('checked')` should return `true` if checked and `false` if not.  So just change your conditional to `if (that.attr('checked'))`